# Selenium /C# Xpath doesn't work though can be searched in the DOM

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, phantomjs

I have been struggling to get the text from the Table.I can get the value from the xpath when I check in firebug but when I run the code it doesn't fetch the value.
The table is given below-

```html
div class="description__table-holder">
<table class="description__table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Test: </td>
<td>9780238905</td>
<td>Pas: </td>
<td>600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Size: </td>
<td>216 x 274mm</td>
<td>   Result: </td>
<td>  9 To 12  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I have tried the following Xpaths-

```
html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/section[1]/section[2]/div[4]/div[1]/article/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]

html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/section[1]/section[2]/div[4]//table[@class='description__table']/tbody/tr[1]

html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/section[1]/section[2]/div[4]/div[1]/article/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/following-sibling::td[3]
```

But when I try to get the value in selenium/c#/phantomJS driver I can't.Below is my code-

```
  var datanew = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/section[1]/section[2]/div[4]//table[@class='description__table']/tbody/tr[1]"));

                    var other = "";
                    ArrayList others = new ArrayList();

                    foreach (var dat in datanew)
                    {

                        //var linkDriver = new FirefoxDriver();                                   
                        other = dat.Text;
                        others.Add(other);

                    }

                    string test = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/section[1]/section[2]/div[4]/div[1]/article/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/following-sibling::td[3]")).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give some wait & check

```
Thread.sleep(15);
string test = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/section[1]/section[2]/div[4]/div[1]/article/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/following-sibling::td[3]")).Text;
```

If you don't provide implicit or explicit wait in your program then it might be possible that some of xpath will fail even though it may work on UI normally. This is because some element takes time to load on UI and so it is not able to find the element & the script fails. Also try your code with [explicit-wait](http://learn-automation.com/explicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver/), that's better approach also I would suggest you to use [relative xpath instead of absolute xpath](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Comment: Hi,I have already tried both implicit and explicit wait but it doesn't work.Though tried this in Java and it works just fine.

Comment: If the above solution worked well then you can mark this answer as correct so that it will be useful for other.

Comment: If it is working in Java, it should have worked in C# also. Don't know what exactly might be the issue, anyway you can also give a try after modifying your xpath, use relative xpath-http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: I have tried every possible way.Tried all the available functions but it doesn't work.